# How to put in a JSON the texts extracted from a PDF with Tika?

Tags: python, json, pdf, ocr, apache-tika

I would like to know if it is possible to put the texts extracted from a PDF with Tika Python into a JSON, so that in the future I can import them into the respective records of a system. Below is the code I'm using to return parsed text from a PDF.

```
from tika import parser

def extract_text(file):
    parsed = parser.from_file(file)
    parsed_text = parsed['content']
    return parsed_text

file_name_with_extension = input("Enter File Name:")
text = extract_text(file_name_with_extension)
print(text)
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this:

```py
from tika import parser
import json  


def extract_text(file):
    parsed = parser.from_file(file)
    parsed_text = json.dumps(parsed_pdf['metadata'] , indent = 2)  
    return parsed_text

text = extract_text('Untitled.pdf')
print(text)
```

output:

```json
{
  "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
  "Creation-Date": "2021-07-31T12:15:55Z",
  "Last-Modified": "2021-07-31T12:15:55Z",
  "Last-Save-Date": "2021-07-31T12:15:55Z",
  "X-Parsed-By": [
    "org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
    "org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser"
  ],
  "X-TIKA:content_handler": "ToTextContentHandler",
  "X-TIKA:embedded_depth": "0",
  "X-TIKA:parse_time_millis": "26",
  "access_permission:assemble_document": "true",
  "access_permission:can_modify": "true",
  "access_permission:can_print": "true",
  "access_permission:can_print_degraded": "true",
  "access_permission:extract_content": "true",
  "access_permission:extract_for_accessibility": "true",
  "access_permission:fill_in_form": "true",
  "access_permission:modify_annotations": "true",
  "created": "2021-07-31T12:15:55Z",
  "date": "2021-07-31T12:15:55Z",
  "dc:format": "application/pdf; version=1.3",
  "dc:title": "Untitled",
  "dcterms:created": "2021-07-31T12:15:55Z",
  "dcterms:modified": "2021-07-31T12:15:55Z",
  "meta:creation-date": "2021-07-31T12:15:55Z",
  "meta:save-date": "2021-07-31T12:15:55Z",
  "modified": "2021-07-31T12:15:55Z",
  "pdf:PDFVersion": "1.3",
  "pdf:charsPerPage": "1393",
  "pdf:docinfo:created": "2021-07-31T12:15:55Z",
  "pdf:docinfo:creator_tool": "Pages",
  "pdf:docinfo:modified": "2021-07-31T12:15:55Z",
  "pdf:docinfo:producer": "",
  "pdf:docinfo:title": "Untitled",
  "pdf:encrypted": "false",
  "pdf:hasMarkedContent": "true",
  "pdf:hasXFA": "false",
  "pdf:hasXMP": "false",
  "pdf:unmappedUnicodeCharsPerPage": "0",
  "producer": "",
  "resourceName": "b'Untitled.pdf'",
  "title": "Untitled",
  "xmp:CreatorTool": "Pages",
  "xmpTPg:NPages": "1"
}
```

Comment: Almost that would need the text to be inside that JSON, not the PDF data. I don't know if you could understand... I misspecified the question, I'll fix it!

Comment: But anyway, it's already helped somehow, not just for me, but maybe for someone else.